# how to update the row on button click in ag grid in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm working with AG-Grid in my front-end application and need to implement a way to update rows when a user clicks an "Edit" button within a row. I've successfully implemented row deletion but need assistance with row updating.

Here's what I've done for row deletion:

I have a "Delete" button within each row.
When the "Delete" button is clicked, I remove the row from the AG-Grid using api.updateRowData({ remove: [selectedRowData] }).
Now, I need guidance on how to update a row when the "Edit" button is clicked. Specifically, I want to:

Extract the data of the selected row when the "Edit" button is clicked.
Display this data in a form or modal to allow the user to make modifications.
Update the AG-Grid with the modified data.
How can I achieve this? Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import React from 'react';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';

function Read(props) {
  const [record, setRecord] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments')
    .then((response) =>{
      console.log(response.data);
      setRecord(response.data);
    })
  }, [])

  function update(data){
    console.log("hello");
  }

const col= [
    { headerName: "Name", field: "name"},
    { headerName: "Email", field: "email"},
    { headerName: "Body", field: "body"},
    {headerName: "", headerClass: 'new-class',
        cellRendererFramework:(params)=>
        <div>
                  <button onClick={() => update(params.data)}>Edit</button>
        </div>}
  ]

  return (
    <>
        <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{height:'400px',
        width: '700px'}}>
        <AgGridReact
            columnDefs={col}
            rowData={record}
            >
        </AgGridReact>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Read;
```

Answer (score -1):

assign an id to it and then pass then id with the update function.Then you can use querySelectors to get that field and update it

Comment: how can i use querySelectors in react. can you please do it  and post it

Comment: suppose we got an id, then in update function, use something like this const updateRow = document.queryselector(id) 
now you got this row to be updated , now see where the data is present that you want to update, simply console.log(updateRow) now find where that data is present then update it.

Comment: bro i can't understand what you are saying? i will get the id but how can i put that value in grid.

Comment: when you get the id , you can get that element, now see which childNode of that element has you data that is to be changed , get to that childNode and change its textContent, this is one of the way